# I can't update from Lion 10.7.5 to El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I just keep getting this appear when downloading from the Apple App Store
[image: this]

Comment: Hello. Did you try re-download file?

Comment: Which Mac are you trying to upgrade, specifically?

Comment: Two options - you might work with Apple Support to narrow down the error or you might need to edit in some specifics. What date is the Mac set to, do any App Store downloads work? Is the Mac hardware compatible with el cap?

Answer (score 1):

Please activate (click on the desktop) your Finder and press the Keys **CMD + Shift + G** copy and paste the following path in the Box and hit Enter.

```
/private/var/folders
```

- Went into the folder **RZ** (if is not present look for the folder **35**). You will see a new folder witch was replaced xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx. In this folder you find the subfolder **C** and into it ***com.apple.appstore***.
- Remove this to your desktop (please don't delete unless you are sure that you have not additional problems).  Restart your mac and try to download EL Capitan from the Appstore again.

**Additional Information:**

If you not able to locate the folder on my steps above open the Terminal copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo find / -name "com.apple.appstore"
```

You need to Enter you Password for search. Remember that you not see any input if you type you password. But the Terminal recognize your input.
You get a list in the Output window of the Terminal with location path in /private/var/folder .

**Note**: If you not use bash as standard Shell you need to type

```
exec bash
```

first before you use the command above.